# Minor - Can I remove more rows than columns and vice-versa?

Tags: linear-algebra

When working with a rectangular matrix I can create(don't know if it's the correct term) a minor by removing rows and columns. But can I remove more columns than rows?

E.g A is a 3x4 matrix, can create a minor by removing row 2 and columns 3,4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  A $k \times k$ minor of an $m \times n$ matrix is the determinant of a matrix obtained by removing $m-k$ rows and $n-k$ columns.

Comment: The specific conditions given in the question are permissible, but only because it results in a square matrix. Removing rows and columns in general is not permissible.